# Node.JS + MySQL connection pooling required?

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

With the [`node-mysql`](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) module, there are two connection options - a single connection and a connection pool. What is the best way to set up a connection to a MySQL database, using a single global connection for all requests, or creating a pool of connections and taking one from the pool for each request? Or is there a better way to do this? Will I run in to problems using just a single shared connection for all requests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maintaining a single connection for the whole app might be a little bit tricky.

Normally, You want to open a connection to your [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) instance, and wait for it to be established.

From this point you can start using the database (maybe start a HTTP(S) server, process the requests and query the database as needed.)

The problem is when the connection gets destroyed (ex. due to a network error).
Since you're using one connection for the whole application, you must reconnect to **MySQL** and somehow queue all queries while the connection is being established. It's relatively hard to implement such functionality properly.

`node-mysql` has a built-in pooler. A pooler, creates a few connections and keeps them in a pool. Whenever you want to close a connection obtained from the pool, the pooler returns it to the pool instead of actually closing it. Connections on the pool can be reused on next open calls.

IMO using a connection pool, is obviously simpler and shouldn't affect the performance much.